# FBconnect in android returns blank screen

Tags: android, fbconnect

I am trying to make an FBconnect application. I got a link http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/

From here I got one java application and another android application. I am getting no error, but problem is that, I am getting white login screen after clicking on connect with facebook button. Please suggest me where did i make mistake..

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you put your Facebook Apps' API key and the Android Hash Key for that Facebook Application? If not just put that two ids and for the Android Facebook hash key generation is almost same like generating keystore for your apk file and for that you need cygwin and openssl installed on your pc to generate that hash key. And even if all of the things are generated fine even if then it is not working then please give me the LogCat results.

Comment: private static final String kApiKey = "109644509099521"; // Enter either your API secret or a callback URL (as described in documentation): private static final String kApiSecret = "9f17ad272fe6d09419a10f4a96172ad5";                                 I have used those keys, one is API key and another is API secret key. Anything is wrong there? or anything missing? and please suggest me how do i send my logcat result?

Comment: Ok... As detailed explanation if you follow my blog step by step then you can get the exact idea of integrating the facebook and android... http://hossaindoula.blogspot.com/2011/06/android-facebook-tutorial.html... There I gave the detailed explanation and for the LogCat, even the tutorial doesn't give you the solution either then ask me... I will tell you how to give LogCat...

Comment: thank you boss. Let me go through the tutorial and letting you know what exactly happens :)